# Tftp put linux one line

Tags: linux, command-line, tftp

I have been following the answer provided in this link : [Put file with tftp client in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/581812/put-file-with-tftp-client-in-linux)

However, I've tried all of the commands listed and always get this response.

```
usage: tftp host-name [port]
```

I use this command on windows: `tftp 192.168.1.100 put filename`

I need the equivalent for linux, I cannot get any options in the thread above to work. tftp always returns usage prompt.

```
$ tftp 192.168.1.100 -m binary -c put filename.hex 
usage: tftp host-name [port]
tftp>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

All options but `-c <command>` need to be before the IP address. See `man tftp` under Linux for further ref

Answer (score 0):

according to man page

> tftp [ options... ] [host [port]] [-c command]

so give a try to

```
tftp -m binary 192.168.1.100 -c put filename.hex
```

if it failed

```
(echo binary ; echo put filename.hex ) | tftp 192.168.1.100
```